# @OneToMany duplicates for every PUT ***UPDATE***

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following entity A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_a")
public class TableA {
    ...
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tableA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TableB> tableBs;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="table_b")
public class TableB {
    ...
    @Column(name="table_a_id")
    private Long tableAId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="table_a_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TableA tableA;
}
```

In my first PUT request, I sent the following:

```
{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{name: "Bname1", tableAId: 1}]}
```

This creates 1 record in table.  Then I add another tableB so I sent the following in PUT request:

```
{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{name: "Bname1", tableAId: 1}, {name: "Bname2", tableAId: 1}]}
```

This creates Bname2 plus another Bname1.  So I have 3 records already.  Then I add another tableB:

```
{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{name: "Bname1", tableAId: 1}, {name: "Bname2", tableAId: 1}, {name: "Bname3", tableAId: 1}]}
```

This creates Bname3 but created another Bname1 and Bname2, now getting 6 records in table_b.  I do this because I thought hibernate will handle the update automatically.  Because I have scenario where I update one tableB record, delete one tableB record and add new tableB record and then send a PUT request. Please advise.

This is my DAO

```
public interface TableADAO extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<TableA>, JpaRepository<TableA, Long>
```

***UPDATE***

I think the duplicate is solved already by setting the "id" in Bname, that is `{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{id: 1, name: "Bname1", tableAId: 1}]}`... previously I send id="".  So even if create new tableA or add tableB, I send id="".   However, still I have issue on the delete.  The scenario is:

1. I add Bname4
2. I updated Bname3
3. I deleted Bname1

Then in the PUT request I send the following:

```
{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{id: 2, name: "Bname2", tableAId: 1}, {id: 3, name: "Bname3_update", tableAId: 1}, {id: "", name: "Bname4", tableAId: 1}]}
```

But still Bname1 is in the table. It's not deleted.  This is my remaining issue.

***2nd UPDATE***
I solved also the delete issue.  I added orphanRemoval=true and from the UI, I I still send the item to be deleted but remove the property "tableAId":

This makes Bname1 orphan and hibernate automatically removes it from table.

`{id: 1, tableAName: "Test", tableBs: [{id: 1, name: "Bname1"}, {id: 2, name: "Bname2", tableAId: 1}, {id: 3, name: "Bname3_update", tableAId: 1}, {id: "", name: "Bname4", tableAId: 1}]}`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tableA", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TableB> tableBs;
```

Comment: it is not useful if you do not show codes that save the record

Comment: it just calls the save() from CrudRepository.  I updated the code

Comment: show your hibernate.cfg.xml file.

Comment: i think i solved it already.  thanks.  i updated the question